# How to pass PHP (index.php file ) Variable value to external JAVASCRIPT .js File?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Actually this code is wrote in `index.php` file but now i want to pass this javascript array value to external js file.

```
<?PHP 
  $qry2 = mysql_query("SELECT table_no FROM table_info");
  while($res2 = mysql_fetch_array($qry2))
  {
    static $i = 0;
    $i++;
    $reg_table[$i] = $res2['table_no']; 
  }
?>


<script>
  var bookedSeats = new Array();
  <?php foreach($reg_table as $key => $val)
  { ?>
    bookedSeats.push('<?php echo $val; ?>');
  <?php }?>
</script>
```

I want the `bookedSeats` variable to be in the external `table.js` file.

Comment: just include table.js after and reference bookedSeats var

Comment: Also, why are you referencing an external script `munna.js`, then proceeding to write code inline? That seems odd

Answer (score 0):

You have jQuery *tag* in there, so I am going to give you this... use Ajax:

**test.php**

```
<?php

// Handle Ajax Request
if (isset($_GET['loadData']))
{
    // Query your db here, im building dummy data
    $results = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
        $results[] = 'Data '. $i;
    }

    // Return Data
    exit(json_encode($results));
}

?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

// Load Data Via Ajax
$.getJSON("test.php?loadData", function(bookedSeats)
{
    console.log(bookedSeats);
});

</script>
```

When the page loads, we get the result like this:

[image]

Comment: You could include a brief explanation of json and how to parse it also.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  var bookedSeats = new Array();
  <?php foreach($reg_table as $key => $val)
  { ?>
    bookedSeats.push('<?php echo $val; ?>');
  <?php }?>
</script>
```

This can be greatly simplified and made immune to XSS:

```
<script>
  var bookedSeats = <?php echo json_encode(array_values($reg_table)); ?>;
</script>
```

You can now refer to `bookedSeats` in your external .js file, but *only* if that file is being run *after* this inline script has been placed. In other words, putting:

```
<script src="external.js"></script>
```

*after* the `<script>...<?php ... ?>...</script>` is okay, but putting it *before* is only okay if you are deferring its execution - it's just safer to put it after ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have an alternative solution for you eventually even if Latheesan Kanes's one is right.

Mine is just given as a trivial exemple if you have access to a constructor in your Javascript object in the table.js file.

```
    <script>
  var bookedSeats = new Array();
person=new Object();
  <?php foreach($reg_table as $key => $val)
  { 
// here a javascript object
?>

person.firstname="John"; // of course replace firstname and John by your informations
  <?php }?>


    // then call table.js constructor
var objectInTableDotJS = new YourConstructor(person); // now in table.js you need to make modification :)
```

Comment: In Table.js you have all your code in Javascript but the content of the variables comes from the php file so it's quite dynamic